# How to use string variable in subprocess.check_output in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I want to run a command having args on linux using python

i have wriiten following code:

```
import subprocess

msg = 'this is commit'
cmdtorun = 'hg commit -m "{}"'.format(msg)

try:
    subprocess.check_output(cmdtorun, shell=True)
    print "commit done"
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print "commit failed
```

but this is giving me error.

Comment: *but this is giving me error* - it'd be useful if you'd share what that error is... Can you run the command by itself - if so - where do you run it - is the working directory of the the Python program in the same place etc...

Comment: don't use `check_output()` unless you need command's output. Use `subprocess.call()` instead e.g.,`print("done" if call(['hg', 'commit', '-m', msg], cwd=repo_dir) == 0 else "failed")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your problem is something else entirely. Check what error you actually get. I'm guessing that you're executing `hg` in the wrong directory (pass in the `cwd=` keyword argument).

Also, your escaping with `'"{}"'.format` is incorrect - it fails when `msg` contains a double quote. You could escape with [`shlex.quote`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote), but that's error-prone. It's far easier to let subprocess do the escaping:

```
import subprocess
msg = 'this is commit'
try:
    subprocess.check_output(['hg', 'commit', '-m', msg])
    print("commit done")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
    print("commit failed: %r" % cpe)
```

Comment: While I agree breaking it up is simpler - I'm not sure *The problem is that the formatting results in the string [...] you would want to properly escape that...* is true. The formatting they're using would result in `hg commit -m "this is commit"` so should be a valid command with `shell=True`...

Comment: @JonClements You're right, I overlooked the quotes. Updated the answer.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the working directory and supplying `cwd` as you now suggest is a nice way for a quick fix - but guess we won't know until the OP pipes up :)